# puppet restrict installed modules based on osfamily

Tags: puppet

I have configured puppet manifest as below,

```
class main_config{
  if $::osfamily == 'windows' {
  }
  else {
    class{main_config::install:} ->
    class{main_config::config:}
  }
}
```

Also I have installed puppet modules that are needed for both Linux and Windows. When I run puppet agent on Linux there are also Windows related modules like powershell exec which are installed and are not needed for Linux absolutely.

I am looking for the way to restrict modules based on OS type to avoid unnecessary modules getting installed.

For example, when I install puppetlabs-powershell puppet module on puppet master, then when I run puppet agent on clients on linux server then this windows module is also getting installed.

Comment: Check this answer https://ask.puppet.com/question/16206/how-to-check-the-operating-system-nameversion-how-to-print-the-message-on-agent-side-according-to-this-os/

Comment: The only real way to pull this off is to separate your Windows and Linux into separate directory environments, but this has its own set of issues that may arise.

Comment: There seem to be some misunderstandings here.  (1) with a master / agent setup, Puppet modules are installed *only* on the master.  (2) whatever modules are installed on the master, which of those are applied to any given target node is controlled by that node's classification, and that is gleaned from one or more of global declarations, a matching node block, and the output of an external node classifier.  In other words, it is completely under your control which modules are applied to which nodes.

Comment: How to exert the available control under your particular circumstances depends, however, on the details of how you are classifying nodes in the first place.  You have not presented that.  Generally, we look for a [mcve] demonstrating your problem in order to be able to make a useful answer.